# Cloudera CDSW URL Access Via Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy

Please help advise me on this tricky situation in my project:

############

In our project we have 3 tiers (web->app->db) for firewall rules. Users can only access Web-Tier.

CDSW application runs on DB host -> We do not have any application host in app-tier -> Due to this we have to setup an extra Apache proxy in App-Tier -> Our current setup is like this:

User -> Apache Proxy (Web-Tier) -> Apache Proxy (App-Tier) -> CDSW (DB-Tier)

CDSW Limitations:
CDSW requires a web url (cdsw.company.com & *.cdsw.company.com) to be registered in remote DNS server - CDSW specifically says local host file is not supported.

Due to this we cannot have same URL (cdsw.company.com) mapped to web-tier & db-tier at same time. For this, we have used a standalone DNS server which is used only by CDSW host.

When user login to CDSW & open a project - 3 other urls are generated (consoles.cdsw.company.com , assets.cdsw.company.com , livelog.cdsw.company.com)

Inside CDSW project - If a user clicks on terminal access then a new browser window opens with dynamic URL generated as: .cdsw.company.com

############

Please advise - How can I make this CDSW application accessible to users via Apache Proxy (web-tier) URL with all these complications stated above.

Regards,
Ashu